# How do I send email in C# app using company's email address(webmail). I tried the following codes below but didn't work

Tags: c#

How do I send email in C# app using company's email address(webmail)? I tried the following code, but didn't work.

It works with gmail but not with webmail.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

private void btnSend_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string from, pass;

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    from = "london.city@COMPANY.org.uk";
    pass = "PASSWORD";
    message.To.Add("ABC@gmail.com");
    message.Subject = "Hello my friend";
    message.From = new MailAddress(from);
    message.Body = "I am feeling good";

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.webmail.COMPANY.org.uk");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, pass);

    try
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
        MessageBox.Show("send successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception et)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(et.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Exception?

Comment: If it works with gmail... then the problem is not the code, even if its horribly formatted... you may be using a user without privileges or wrong server settings or something like that

Comment: Does your webmail support ssl on port 25? Your webmail may also require a different form or authentication... Such as domain user vs email address.